# Firebase project not showing in Google Analytics

Tags: firebase, google-analytics

I have a **firebase** project that has **Google Analytics** enabled.
[image]

and when I click **Manage**, there is a link to **Google Analytics**.
[image]
But in **Google Analytics** it is not showing at all.

Comment: I am also facing same issue, is this resolved?